# Passing params with router.back()

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-router

I'm using expo-router and need to pass some params back. How to do that?

I use router push here:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.qrButton} onPress={()=> {router.push(`/rent-bike/qr-scanner`)}}>
                    <Text style={styles.qrText}>Użyj kodu QR</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

Then I scan QR code and want to pass it back to display on same page:

```
    const handleBarCodeScanned = ({type, data}) => {
        setScanData(true)
        console.log(`data: ${data}`);
        console.log(`type: ${type}`);
        router.back()
    };
```

I can't see any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `router.replace` instead of `goBack()`. That way you can add params: `router.replace({pathname: 'some-path', params: {param: qrData }})`.

Comment: This sort of works, but the visual effect has the screen moving in from the right instead of from the left